List Validation Yearly Reset
I maintain a tracker of budgets. Once a budget is authorized, that marks the Annual Budget Effective date. Each Budget Effective year marks that budgets anniversary, which resets the budget.
For example, a budget has an effective date of 02-01-24, on 02-01-25, the budget resets. A year goes by and the budget resets again on 02-01-26, and so on.
Within the budgets yearly life cycle, amendments can be made to increase the total amount. the cumulative total of those increases cannot be greater than $1000. Each increase is tracked for the year. On the same row, the date of the amendment is noted, along with the amount of the increase. However, once the budget resets, a new row must be created to track the next set of amendments & dates for that following year.
I am seeking a list validation formula or a column formula (which ever will work best), that will prevent any additional amendment entries after each budget anniversary month/year. If someone goes to add an amendment date on the same row, after the anniversary month/year, an error message will appear.
Using the above example, the initial budget effective date is 02-01-24 (this never changes), once 02-01-25 has passed, no more dates/amendment amounts can be entered, and an error message appears, indicting a new row needs to be created. On that new row, the initial budget effective date of
02-01-24 is maintained, once 02-01-26 passes, no more dates/amendment amounts can be entered, and an error message appears, indicting a new row needs to be created, and so on.
Although the original budget effective Month/Year never changes, I would need the formula to flag this yearly.
Hopefully this makes sense. Thank you in advance!!
